# Java | Custom Created Package Does not Exist

Tags: java, package, classpath, method-call

### Purpose

- I want to be able to create a package and call it.
- Alternatively, I would like to create separate files for my method (to avoid having x classes in one file).

### Setup

Here is my LetterGrader.java file:

```
package grade.util;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LetterGrader {
  private void readArgs() {
          System.out.println("Hello, read CLA!");
  }
}
```

Here is my TestLetterGrader.java file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TestLetterGrader {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LetterGrader letterGrader = new LetterGrader(); // instantiate
        letterGrader.readArgs(); // call method
  }
}
```

### Steps Taken

1. First, I compile LetterGrader:

   - This auto creates the bin/grade/util/LetterGrader.class file

     > javac -d bin -sourcepath src src/grade/util/LetterGrader.java

[Here is my working directory at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr0fj.png)

2. Second, I compile TestLetterGrader:

   - This fails

> javac -d bin -sourcepath src src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java

The error message:

```
src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    LetterGrader letterGrader = new LetterGrader(); // instantiate
    ^
  symbol:   class LetterGrader
  location: class TestLetterGrader
```

### Question

- I believe I am misunderstanding how to call a classes from separate files (in the same location). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing class that is in bin folder. Don’t do that it would not work. You don’t need any import, because the classes are in the same place. Make package under src folder and place the classes there. Remove `package grade.util` and rename it to the package where you place the classes.

File structure:

```
src
 \ 
  \
  yourpackage 
       \
        \
    LetterGrader.java   TestLetterGrader.java
```

Then delete everything in your build folder and compile the classes. Java will make it’s magic. You do need to worry about bin folder, it is only for storing compiled classes.

Classes will look like this:

```
//package name that you created
package yourpackage;

public class LetterGrader {
//need to be public when calling from another class
public void readArgs() {
        System.out.println("Hello, read CLA!");
}
}
```

And

```
//folder that you placed the .java files
package yourpackage;
//without any import

public class TestLetterGrader {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LetterGrader letterGrader = new LetterGrader(); // instantiate
        letterGrader.readArgs(); // call method
  }
}
```

Your second question:

You can use classes from other folders, but you you have to import them and they have to be under src folder.

Tell you have class A.java in folder Second and class B.java in folder Main. You will import the the folder in this case `import Second.A;` 
And then call the class `A a = new A();` 
When you have method in a that you want to call simply do:
`a.yourmethod();`

You have to change `private void ...` to `public void...` because you cannot call private outside of the class.

When you are running compiled classes they have to be in the same folder.

Comment: Does this helped you?

Comment: ```Java will make it’s magic. You do need to worry about bin folder, it is only for storing compiled classes.```

I am a bit lost on that. Can you indicate what command that would be? 

I am working with the following understanding: 
1. I have to compile classes 
2. Ideally not great practice to mix .classes and .java files. 

With that said, I did the following. 
1. Built ran ```javac LetterGrader.java``` so that class is in the same folder with .java files. 
2. Removed import stmt from ```TestLetterGrader```. 

Still have the same error, though

Comment: You have to make folder under src and place the .java files in the folder. Then in your both classes add ```package yourfoldername ;``` Java makes the magic: Java will automatically after compilation command place compiled classes into the bin folder

Comment: Thanks @maratonec. I had some trouble adding my exact steps to this comment. I updated my question with the exact steps taken after your suggestion (stills resembles original question). Mind taking a look and letting me know what I am missing again? I am thinking it is a misunderstanding on my part. I believe I a followed your suggestion but still ran into an error.

Comment: You had to add ```package grade.util``` to both your classes

Comment: I have your error! Your method is private and you can’t call private methods outside of class

Comment: I added `package grade.util;` to `TestLetterGrader.java`. That allowed TestLetterGrader.java to compile into a class file. I also made the methods in LetterGrader public and recompiled. But when I tried to execute TestLetterGrader.java it says LetterGrader doesn't exist.

Comment: What java version are u using. For me the code work! I am using JDK 8

Comment: Are the compiled classes in same folder

Comment: Error:

java src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java 
src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    LetterGrader letterGrader = new LetterGrader(); // instantiate
    ^
  symbol:   class LetterGrader
  location: class TestLetterGrader
src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    LetterGrader letterGrader = new LetterGrader(); // instantiate
                                    ^
  symbol:   class LetterGrader
  location: class TestLetterGrader
2 errors

Comment: java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: Compiled classes in bin/grade/util/ *.classes. 

Java files in src/grade/util/*.java. 

Command: java src/grade/util/TestLetterGrader.java.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @maratonec for the guidance.

My initial mistake was that I was  misunderstanding/misassigning the classpath assignment variable when running a program via terminal. The below helped me.

Compiling and Running a Java Program (on a PC)

• Set the working directory (say, JavaBook) 
`C:\> cd JavaBook`

• Compile HelloWorld.java
`C:\JavaBook> javac -d bin src\HelloWorld.java`

•Run the program 
`C:\JavaBook> java -classpath bin HelloWorld`

Also, the approach of having all my class files in the same location simplified things. I didn't have to worry about classpath. But not ideal as I have many files to work with.

As for the package creation, I am going to play around with java a bit more before using it. I think I need to solidify my understanding.

Thanks for helping me!